# Many-To-Many sort over number in joining table

Tags: android, ormlite

I'm having 2 classes that needs have relation many to many. First class (`Connection`) aggregates second class (`City`) in defined by my order (look `Connection<City>` number).

The problem is that when I get all Connections and set path (`Collection<City>`) order in path is by City id not number.

Here are my classes:

```
@DatabaseTable
public class Connection implements Serializable {    
    @DatabaseField(generatedId = true, columnName = ID)
    private int mId;
    private Collection<City> mPath;

    public void setPath(List<City> path) {
        mPath = path;
    }
}
```

[**Connection.java class**](https://github.com/magx2/transport/blob/8bbbd7c37e6274d2609fca33d88088a40b511f62/android-Transport/transport/src/main/java/pl/grzeslowski/transport/model/Connection.java)

```
@DatabaseTable
public class City implements Serializable {
    @DatabaseField(generatedId = true, columnName = ID)
    private int mId;
    @DatabaseField(columnName = NAME, unique = true, canBeNull = false)
    private String mName;
}
```

[**City.java class**](https://github.com/magx2/transport/blob/8bbbd7c37e6274d2609fca33d88088a40b511f62/android-Transport/transport/src/main/java/pl/grzeslowski/transport/model/City.java)

```
@DatabaseTable
public class ConnectionCity {
    public static final String CONNECTION = "cc_connection";
    public static final String CITY = "cc_city";
    public static final String NUMBER = "cc_number";

    @DatabaseField(generatedId = true)
    private int mId;
    @DatabaseField(foreign = true, canBeNull = false, columnName = CONNECTION)
    private Connection mConnection;
    @DatabaseField(foreign = true, canBeNull = false, columnName = CITY)
    private City mCity;
    @DatabaseField(canBeNull = false, columnName = NUMBER)
    private int mNumber; // I want to order by this
}
```

[**ConnecionCity.java class**](https://github.com/magx2/transport/blob/8bbbd7c37e6274d2609fca33d88088a40b511f62/android-Transport/transport/src/main/java/pl/grzeslowski/transport/model/ConnectionCity.java)

`DatabseHelper`:

```
public Collection<Connection> getAllConnections() {
    try {
        final List<Connection> connections = mConnectionDao.queryForAll();

        for (Connection connection : connections) {
            List<City> path = lookUpForCities(connection);

            connection.setPath(path);
        }

        return connections;
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

private List<City> lookUpForCities(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
    PreparedQuery<City> postsForUserQuery = makeCitiesForConnectionQuery();
    postsForUserQuery.setArgumentHolderValue(0, connection);
    return mCityDao.query(postsForUserQuery);
}

private PreparedQuery<City> makeCitiesForConnectionQuery() throws SQLException {

    // build our inner query for UserPost objects
    QueryBuilder<ConnectionCity, Integer> connectionCityQb = mConnectionCityDao.queryBuilder();

    // just select the post-id field
    connectionCityQb.selectColumns(ConnectionCity.CITY);
    SelectArg userSelectArg = new SelectArg();

    // you could also just pass in user1 here
    connectionCityQb.where().eq(ConnectionCity.CONNECTION, userSelectArg);
    connectionCityQb.orderBy(ConnectionCity.NUMBER, true);

    // build our outer query for Post objects
    QueryBuilder<City, Integer> cityQb = mCityDao.queryBuilder();

    // where the id matches in the post-id from the inner query
    cityQb.where().in(City.ID, connectionCityQb);

    return cityQb.prepare();
}
```

[**DatabaseHeler.java class**](https://github.com/magx2/transport/blob/8bbbd7c37e6274d2609fca33d88088a40b511f62/android-Transport/transport/src/main/java/pl/grzeslowski/transport/repository/DatabaseHelper.java)

Comment: You should think about changing the relation because Many to Many is rather a bad idea. It's told too avoid such relations .

Comment: One to many would work here?